# Convolution involving the inverse Fourier transform

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

Suppose $$F(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int f(x) e^{ikx} dx$$
and

$$G(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int g(x)e^{ikx} dx$$

Where $F(K),G(K)$ are Fourier transforms. Then how can I write the convolution of $F$ and $G$ so that

$$F *G = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int f(x)g(x)e^{ikx} dx$$

Where $*$ is the convolution?

I know that if $$f(x) = \int F(K)e^{-ikx} dx$$
$$g(x) = \int G(K)e^{-ikx} dx$$

Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int g(x-x')f(x')dx' = f(x) = \int F(K)G(K)e^{-ikx} dx$$

What would the expression of the Fourier transform of $f(x)g(x)$ be in terms of $F(K)$ and $G(K)$

Comment: Why do you call it inverse of the convolution. When it exists, a convolution in the primal domain ($x$) is a product in the dual domain  ($k$) and vice-versa

Comment: Because I only the Fourier transform involving the transform, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how do I write the convolution" or what this question has to do with an inverse of the convolution theorem.

Comment: @user7530 What would the expression of the Fourier transform of $f(x)g(x)$ be in terms of $F(K)$ and $G(K)$

Comment: @Dman : the Fourier transform of $f \cdot g$ is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) of the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Would that be $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int G(k-k')F(k')dk'?$$

Comment: Try to do the same as the LHS of your last equation; replacing $g(x-x')$ by  $G(k-k')$, so for $f$, split the cisoid, swap integral. The same reasoning applies

Comment: @LaurentDuval like I did above?

Comment: @Dman You stated a result you know. If you know how to prove it, the same lines should work